# Remove SELECT options based on another SELECT selected

Tags: reactjs

```
const initData = [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Type A",
      "description":"Description Type A"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Type B",
      "description":"Description Type B"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Type C",
      "description":"Description Type C"
   }
]
const [listOption, setListOption] =  useState(initData);
```

I have two select dropdown `exampleA`, `exampleB` like this.

```
              <CSelect
                custom
                name="exampleA" // exampleB
                id="exampleA" // exampleB
                onChange={(e) => {                          
                 //someFunctionToCheck(e, i);
                }}                       
              >
                {listOption &&
                  listOption.map((x) => {
                    return (
                      <option
                        value={x.id}
                        key={"key" + x.id}
                      >
                        {x.name}
                      </option>
                    );
                  })}
              </CSelect>
```

I want it so that when the user selects `"name":"Type A"` in `exampleA`, on `exampleB` user can only choose `"name":"Type B"`, `"name":"Type C"`.

Or if user selects `"name":"Type B"` in `exampleA`, on `exampleB` user can only choose `"name":"Type A"`, `"name":"Type C"`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the state based on the value of your select:

```
const someFunctionToCheck = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setListOption(initData.filter(entry => entry.id !== parseInt(e.target.value)))
}
```

This would work however if you want both your selects to be filtered on either one's selected value. If you want to filter only the other element's choices, just use two different states (see full code below or here https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-snowflake-wf6w6?file=/src/App.js:0-1572)

Notice the filter is on initData, so as to put the unselected values back.

Full working code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const initData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Type A",
      description: "Description Type A"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Type B",
      description: "Description Type B"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Type C",
      description: "Description Type C"
    }
  ];
  const [listOption, setListOption] = useState(initData);
  const [listOption2, setListOption2] = useState(initData);
  const someFunctionToCheck = (e, i) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (i === 1)
      setListOption2(
        initData.filter((entry) => entry.id !== parseInt(e.target.value))
      );
    else if (i === 2)
      setListOption(
        initData.filter((entry) => entry.id !== parseInt(e.target.value))
      );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        name="Type A"
        onChange={(e) => {
          someFunctionToCheck(e, 1);
        }}
      >
        {listOption &&
          listOption.map((x) => {
            return (
              <option value={x.id} key={"key" + x.id}>
                {x.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
      </select>
      <select
        name="Type B"
        onChange={(e) => {
          someFunctionToCheck(e, 2);
        }}
      >
        {listOption &&
          listOption2.map((x) => {
            return (
              <option value={x.id} key={"key" + x.id}>
                {x.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```